# Code for 8 point DCT using shifters and adders

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I've written code for an 8 point dct using shifters and adders. I didn't get any errors but while simulating I didn't get the expected result.

Logically it is correct, as I have mathematically solved it. Please help me to resolve this flaw.

Expected pattern is

```
X(0)=5                                 y(0)=1792  
X(1)=4                                 y(1)=710  
X(2)=2                                 y(2)=-191
X(3)=1                                 y(3)=-153
X(4)=6                                 y(4)=-128
X(5)=7                                 y(5)=301
X(6)=2                                 y(6)=-213
X(7)=1                                 y(7)=-70
```

```verilog
module dct_8(clk,x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,y0,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7
        );
    input clk;
    input [2:0] x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7;
    output [15:0] y0,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7;
    wire[10:0] t089,t075,t050,t018,t189,t175,t150,t118,t289,t275,t250,t218,t389,t375,t350,t318;
    wire[3:0] f0,f1,f2,f3,z0,z1,z2,z3;

    input_adder_8 m(clk,x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,f0,f1,f2,f3,z0,z1,z2,z3);  //a0=f0,b0=z0
    new w(clk,f0,f1,f2,f3,y0,y2,y4,y6);
    shift_adder_8a p0(clk,z0,t089,t075,t050,t018);
    shift_adder_8b p1(clk,z1,t189,t175,t150,t118);
    shift_adder_8c p2(clk,z2,t289,t275,t250,t218);
    shift_adder_8d p3(clk,z3,t389,t375,t350,t318); 

    output_adder_8a q(clk,t089,t318,t175,t250,y1);
     output_adder_8b r(clk,t289,t075,t350,t118,y3);
     output_adder_8c s(clk,t189,t375,t050,t218,y5);
     output_adder_8d t(clk,t389,t275,t150,t018,y7);

    endmodule


module input_adder_8(clk,x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,f0,f1,f2,f3,z0,z1,z2,z3);
input clk;
input [2:0] x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7;
output reg[3:0] f0,f1,f2,f3,z0,z1,z2,z3;

    always@(posedge clk)
    begin

     f0<=x0+x7;
     z0<=x0-x7;
     f1<=x1+x6;
     z1<=x1-x6;
     f2<=x2+x5;
     z2<=x2-x5;
     f3<=x3+x4;
     z3<=x3-x4;
     end
    endmodule


module shift_adder_8a(clk,z0,t089,t075,t050,t018);
input clk;
input [3:0]z0;
output reg[10:0]t089,t075,t050,t018;
reg [6:0] u0,v0;

always@(posedge clk )
begin

 u0 <= (z0<<3)+z0;
 v0 <= (z0<<4)+u0;
 t089 <= (z0<<6)+v0;
 t075 <= (v0<<1)+v0;
 t050 <= (v0<<1);
 t018 = (u0<<1);

 end
endmodule

module shift_adder_8b(clk,z1,t189,t175,t150,t118);
input clk;
input [3:0]z1;
output reg[10:0]t189,t175,t150,t118;
reg [6:0] u1,v1;

always@(posedge clk )
begin

u1 <= (z1<<3)+z1;
v1 <= (z1<<4)+u1;
t189 <= (z1<<6)+v1;
t175 <= (v1<<1)+v1;
t150 <= (v1<<1);
t118 <= (u1<<1);
end
endmodule


module shift_adder_8c(clk,z2,t289,t275,t250,t218);
input clk;
input [3:0]z2;
output reg[10:0]t289,t275,t250,t218;
reg [6:0] u2,v2;

always@(posedge clk )
begin

u2 <= (z2<<3)+z2;
v2 <= (z2<<4)+u2;
t289 <= (z2<<6)+v2;
t275 <= (v2<<1)+v2;
t250 <= (v2<<1);
t218 <= (u2<<1);
end
endmodule

module shift_adder_8d(clk,z3,t389,t375,t350,t318);
input clk;
input [3:0]z3;
output reg[10:0]t389,t375,t350,t318;
reg [6:0] u3,v3;

always@(posedge clk )
begin

u3 <= (z3<<3)+z3;
v3 <= (z3<<4)+u3;
t389 <= (z3<<6)+v3;
t375 <= (v3<<1)+v3;
t350 <= (v3<<1);
t318 <= (u3<<1);
end
endmodule

module output_adder_8a(clk,t089,t318,t175,t250,y1);
input clk;
input [10:0] t089,t175,t250,t318;
output reg[15:0] y1;
reg [11:0] c,d;

always@(posedge clk)
begin

 c<= t089+t318;
 d<= t175+t250;
 y1<= c+d;
end
endmodule

module output_adder_8b(clk,t289,t075,t350,t118,y3);
input clk;
input [10:0] t289,t075,t350,t118;
output reg[15:0] y3;
reg [11:0] e,f;
always@(posedge clk)
begin
 e<= t289+t118;
 f<= t075-t350;
 y3<=f-e;
 end
endmodule

module output_adder_8c(clk,t189,t375,t050,t218,y5);
input clk;
input [10:0] t189,t375,t050,t218;
output reg[15:0] y5;
reg [11:0] g,h;
always@(posedge clk)
begin
 g<= t218-t189;
 h<= t375+t050;
 y5<=g+h;
 end
endmodule

module output_adder_8d(clk,t389,t275,t150,t018,y7);
input clk;
input [10:0] t389,t275,t150,t018;
output reg[15:0] y7;
reg [11:0] i,j;
always@(posedge clk)
begin
 i<= t018-t389;
 j<= t275-t150;
 y7<=i+j;
 end
endmodule



//code for 4 dct used in above module


module new(clk,x0,x1,x2,x3,y0,y1,y2,y3);
input clk;
input [3:0]x0,x1,x2,x3;
output [15:0]y0,y1,y2,y3;

wire [4:0]a0,a1,b0,b1;
wire [10:0] t08,t03,t13,t18,t06,t16;

input_adder m1(clk,x0,x1,x2,x3,a0,a1,b0,b1);
shift p1(clk,a0,a1,b0,b1,t08,t03,t18,t13,t06,t16);
output_adder z1(clk,t08,t03,t13,t18,t06,t16,y0,y1,y2,y3);

endmodule
module input_adder(clk,k0,k1,k2,k3,m0,m1,n0,n1);
input clk;
input [3:0]k0,k1,k2,k3;
output reg[4:0] m0,m1,n0,n1;
always@(posedge clk)
begin
m0<=k0+k3;
n0<=k0-k3;
m1<=k1+k2;
n1<=k1-k2;
end
endmodule

module shift(clk,m0,m1,n0,n1,s08,s03,s18,s13,s06,s16);
input clk;
input [4:0]m0,m1,n0,n1;
output reg [10:0]s08,s03,s18,s13,s06,s16;
reg  [9:0]p0,q0,p1,q1;
always@( posedge clk)
begin
s06=m0<<6;
s16=m1<<6;
p0= (n0<<3)+n0;
q0= p0<<1;
s03=q0<<1;
s08=(n0<<6)+q0+n0;
p1= (n1<<3)+n1;
q1= p1<<1;
s13=q1<<1;
s18= (n1<<6)+q1+n1;
 //assign s06=m0<<6;
 //assign s16=m1<<6;
 end
 endmodule

module output_adder(clk,s08,s03,s13,s18,s06,s16,c0,c1,c2,c3);
input clk;
input [10:0] s08,s03,s18,s13,s06,s16;
output reg [15:0] c0,c1,c2,c3;

always@(posedge clk)
begin
c0<=s06+s16;
c1<=s08+s13;
c2<=s06-s16;
c3<=s03-s18;
end
endmodule
```

> WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <q1> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <q0> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <p1> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <p0> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <s06_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <p1>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <c0_12> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <z1>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t018_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <p0>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t118_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <p1>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t218_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <p2>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t318_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <p3>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <y1_13> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <q>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <y5_13> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <s>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <y7_13> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <t>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <t050<10:8>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8a>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <t018<10:8>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8a>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <t150<10:8>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8b>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <t118<10:8>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8b>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <t250<10:8>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8c>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <t218<10:8>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8c>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <t350<10:8>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8d>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <t318<10:8>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8d>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <y1<15:13>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <output_adder_8a>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <y5<15:13>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <output_adder_8c>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <y7<15:13>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <output_adder_8d>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <c0<15:12>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <output_adder>.
>       WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <c1<15:12>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <output_adder>.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t018_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8a>.  This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <t050_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8a>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t118_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8b>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <t150_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8b>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t218_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8c>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>   WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <t250_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8c>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>   WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t318_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8d>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <t350_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8d>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <s06_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s06_1> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s06_2> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s06_3> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s06_4> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s06_5> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s16_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s16_1> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s16_2> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s16_3> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s16_4> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s16_5> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s03_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s03_1> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s13_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s13_1> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t075_9> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8a>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <t075_10> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8a>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t175_9> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8b>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <t175_10> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8b>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t275_9> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8c>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <t275_10> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8c>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <t375_9> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8d>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <t375_10> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <shift_adder_8d>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <q/d_11> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <q/d_10> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s/h_11> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <s/h_10> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c0_5> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c0_4> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c0_3> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c0_2> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c0_1> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c0_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c2_5> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c2_4> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c2_3> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c2_2> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c2_1> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>       WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <w/z1/c2_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <dct_8>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: i didnt get ur point...plzz elaborate it. it gives no error in check and syntax....so i debug it any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning messages are self descriptive and you are only dealing with four types:

> WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <***signal_name***> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <***signal_name***> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <***hierarchy_name***>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:2404 - FFs/Latches <***signal_name***> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <***hierarchy_name***>.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <***signal_name***> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <***hierarchy_name***>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

The warnings do not mean anything is functionally wrong and will still pass logical equivalency checks. It is always a good idea to review the warnings, but you don't necessarily need to change your RTL. I'd highly recommend reviewing the *Xst:646* warnings as it is suggesting there is unnecessary logic in your design or a hookup problem you didn't catch in RTL simulation.

Most of the warnings are reporting that the synthesizer has implemented a more optimized (lower gate/flop count) then inferred from the RTL it started with.

For example, there are warning on `t318` in `shift_adder_8d`. `t318` is defined as a 11-bit register and it is assigned to `(u3<<1)` where `u3` is an 7-bit register. No matter what value of `u3`, `t318[10:8]` will always be `3'b0` (*Xst:2404*) and `t318[0]` will always be `1'b0` (*Xst:1710*). The warnings on this signal should go away (or reduce) if you re-code it to:

```
initial begin
  // ... other inits ....
  t318 = 11'b0;
end
always @(posedge clk)
begin
  // ... other assigns ...
  t318[7:1] <= u3;
end
```

Is the re-coding worth the effort? That is up to you, your instructor, and/or teammates. Generally I recommend trying to resolve warnings unless it negatively impacts readability, scalability, flexibility, etc. This will keep the warning count low and easier to identify useful/surprise warnings (ex: dead code & width miss-matches).

---

<sub>Other note: I'd recommend renaming your ***module new*** to something more meaningful. It is okay in Verilog, but if you every enable SystemVerilog you are going to run into issues. SystemVerilog added reserved keywords *new, bit, byte, int, logic*, and many others on top of Verilog's reserved keywords. For the full list of reserved keywords see [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 22.14.2 *IEEE 1364-1995 keywords* through § 22.14.8 *IEEE 1800-2012 keywords*</sub>

Comment: for warning  Xst:646 <signal> ...these signals are used in my coding...dont know why they get trimmed.....and if we want to consider them...how to do that. and how to remove hookup problem?

Comment: You coded `q0`,`q1`,`p0`,`p1` in a way that at first glance look like flops but after evaluations they are intermediate combination logic. The waring is about the flop for these signals not being used, the comb-logic for it is still being used. If you really want them as flops use non-blocking assignment (`<=`), but this will make output of `s03`,`s18`,etc. arrive 2 clocks latter. It is better to move the intermediate logic to comb block (`always @*`)This will remove the ambiguity of what should be a flop and what should be pure comb-logic. Examples: [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/SKY)